# How to get Shiny boxes from Siege Battles

Tags: summoners-war

Since I'm in a rather small guild we don't have the manpower to regularly earn Shiny trophy boxes (or to dish out enough punishment to get far enough).

[image: Oh Shiny]

As it seems they become available from B- grade and up and the higher you're ranked the more boxes you get, but who is actually eligible to open them? Is it completely random or first come, first serve or do you have to do a certain amount/percentage of damage in order to become eligible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "shiny boxes" that are received in siege battles are, as far as I know, completely random, and all players can get them, no matter how much was contributed.

Comment: Confirmed. I managed to receive a shiny box with a 2nd account that contributed almost nothing but some defenses.